# How to get data from jsp page between two dates and generate PDF or Excel reports

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I am now working on java project till i had completed to get data from database and display it in table as datagrid in jsp page then that data to be converted to PDF or Excel report also done. But now my Problem is if to take history of data i have to refer date from and to date between two date i have to display data in PDF or Excel now i had strucked in that process please can anyone tell me how to do that.

with advance thanks.......!

Comment: a bit of code will help us help you better

Comment: what query are you firing on the database to get the data in the datagrid in the jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you know how to get the data from your DB (between the two dates) and your only problem is to output it to pdf/excel. The easiest and fastest way I would implement it is by output to CSV format - set the response header like this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition:", "attachment; filename="output-filename.csv";
            response.setHeader("Authorization", utils.getSafeHeader(request, "Authorization", null));
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```